# Where are WordPress default widget files or functions located?

Tags: wordpress, tags, widget

I'm trying to slightly modify the default WordPress tag cloud widget.  I don't want to create my own widget because I literally want to adjust one small thing.  I've looked through my WordPress installation but can't find the PHP file that contains the basic widgets.

Even though I assume that they are defined in each theme, I still looked in the core directories but came up empty handed.

So if any of you happen to have already figured this out, please make my life easier and let me know where I can find the default widgets...most importantly the tag cloud widget.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Those are located in the default widget class:

```
/wp-includes/default-widgets.php
```

For more detail:
http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Widgets/WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud.html

The widget invokes a function deeper though that generates the actual output. You'll want to take a look at the `wp_tag_cloud` and `wp_generate_tag_cloud` functions in:

```
/wp-includes/category-template.php
```

Comment: Link to source of the files on Github for the lazy (like me): [/wp-includes/default-widgets.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php) [/wp-includes/category-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/category-template.php).

Answer (score 2):

do take into account however that you'll lose your change when you upgrade wordpress (which is why I eventually did create [my own shabby category-cloud widget](http://blog.futtta.be/2009/01/23/put-your-wordpress-categories-back-in-the-tagcloud/) instead of changing the default tag-cloud code).

Answer (score 1):

The tag cloud widget is defined near the bottom of the `default-widgets.php` file in the `wp-includes` folder.